# Modules Page: Keep Package Sections collapsed

Tags: 7, users

As I'm working over and over with modules, I'm constantly having to scroll past all of the Core modules and such. I can collapse module packages, but when I reload the page they are all expanded again. Is there any way to make drupal remember which module packages to remain collapsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a different approach, but installing the [Module Filter](http://drupal.org/project/module_filter) module will allow you to quickly filter the list of modules by simply typing a few letters of the module's name.  Alternately, you can quickly show only the modules from the categories that you would like to see by using the vertical tabs it places on the left-hand side of the page.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Module Filter (which is great) there are also a couple of settings provided by the [Admin Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aw8A.png) module that might help out:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't 'remember' which ones you've last had open though, it collapses them all every time the page is re-loaded.

Comment: I can't find these 'advanced settings'.
Where exactly is the Admin Menu?